# Update table view data after segue from detail

Tags: ios, tableview

I have got a problem. I need to update data of master view data on segue from detail view. I've tried to implement prepareForSegue method, but it's not called on tapping back button.

What's the way i can do that?

Comment: Use a delegate that can be called when you hit choose whatever you wish in the detail view, that will then allow you to call it and thus in the master view you will receive the call and be able to act upon it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepare for segue doesn't get called when popping a view controller from the navigation stack. I'd suggest calling `[tableView reloadData]` either in the detail view's `viewWillDisappear` method, or in the master view's `viewWillAppear` method. Alternatively, if you want to reload your table view after making a change, you can try using notifications. Something like the following in your master view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refresh:) name:@"RefreshMasterNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)refresh:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And something like the following whenever you make a change in your detail view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshMasterNotification"];
```